# Characteristic polynomial $p(x) = (2 + x) (-x) (1-x)$ and possible matrices problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

I'm asked to find, if possible, a non triangular matrix which has $p(x) = (2 + x) (-x) (1-x)$ as its characteristic polynomial.

The book doesn't describe any method to do this, and after a while thinking I couldn't remember any process. So I searched here for other people struggling with the same problem and I found about the companion matrix. I managed to solve the problem, finding the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.

But this doesn't fully satisfy me, because I was thinking I should be able to solve this problem without having to resort to other methods not described in the book... What am I missing?

Comment: begin with a diagonal matrix $D$ with your desired eigenvalues, then pick your favorite nonsingular matrix $P$    and  use $A = P D P^{-1}  $

Comment: Can you find a triangular matrix $T$ that has that characteristic polynomial? If you can (which should be relatively straightforward), then find a conjugate $QTQ^{-1}$ which is not triangular, which again should not be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes companion matrix solves the question.

But, as the 3 eigenvalues $-2,0,1$ are distinct, any matrix with these eigenvalues can be written in terms of conjugation:

$$M=P \ \text{diag}(-2,0,1) \ P^{-1}$$

where $P$ is any $3 \times 3$ invertible matrix.